# ScalaFX (JavaFX): Stage content does not resize on window resize

Tags: java, scala, javafx, scalafx

To inspect this unexpected behavior, I simply put a `TextArea` directly into the `Scene` contained by the `PrimaryStage`: On app start, the `TextArea` exactly fits the window (as expected).

**But the size of the `TextArea` does not change if I move the window's borders, which is the problem I am trying to solve.**

**[Please see my Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frqmL.png)**

This is my ScalaFX code (which I expect to act exactly like its JavaFX equivalent):

```
object MyApp extends JFXApp {
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "My App"
    resizable = true // has no effect
    maxWidth = Double.MaxValue // has no effect
    maxHeight = Double.MaxValue // has no effect

    val outputDisplay = new TextArea {
      resizable = true // has no effect
      maxWidth = Double.MaxValue // has no effect
      maxHeight = Double.MaxValue // has no effect
      hgrow = Priority.Always // has no effect
      vgrow = Priority.Always // has no effect
    }

    scene = new Scene {
      resizable = true // has no effect
      maxWidth = Double.MaxValue // has no effect
      maxHeight = Double.MaxValue // has no effect
      fill = LightGreen

      // add outputDisplay as content
      content = outputDisplay
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The JavaFX equivalent acts as expected; the `TextArea` fills the scene.

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with my code? Thank you for this information. I gonna try to port it to Java and see if it is an Ubuntu issue...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but I am not a Scala programmer, so. But I tested the JavaFX equivalent (without the "has no effect" lines) and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you. This helps me understand how JavaFX works. In fact I am groping around in the dark and even tried to solve it with an AnchorPane (without success) because the JFXApp's behavior made me think it is necessary to use a pane to make it resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `TextArea` to resize properly you need a layout. For example `BorderPane` should be used as scene's `content`.

More about layouts can found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102

> ### UPDATE
>
> After looking at the ScalaFX source code,I realized that `root` should be used instead of `content` on the scene

Comment: [JavaFX 8 version of the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102). Typically, the root will be resized to fill the scene, whether or not it is a subclass of `Pane`.

Comment: Many thanks, Eugene. Using `root` instead of `content` makes it resize (thus work as expected). I already gave up hoping for such an easy bug in my code, but still it was such an easy bug :-)  Now I can start enjoying JavaFX+Scala on Ubuntu!